# Как правильно написать слово "не/дорого"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, наречия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется слово "недорого" в следующем диалоге:

*— Эта квартира стоит 700 евро.

— Мм... это дорого.

— Нет, это **недорого**.*

Слово "недорого" в данном случае пишется слитно или все-таки раздельно, т.к. есть слово "нет"?

Answer (score 6):

По общему правилу НЕ с наречиями пишется раздельно, если есть/подразумевается противопоставление или утверждается отрицание: не дорого, а дёшево, отрицается дороговизна.
В противном случае - слитно: утверждается, что дёшево.
В Вашем случае возможно двоякое толкование, поэтому окончательное решение за Вами: отрицаете высокую цену - не дорого, утверждаете, что дёшево - недорого. Слово "Нет" не влияет на написание.
Я больше склоняюсь к отрицанию, поэтому написала бы раздельно.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова исправила оформление диалога.

Comment: Да, спасибо, поправила ответ.